# Closing tabs in browser using Logitech mx anywhere 2s

Tags: logitech-mouse

I recently bought this mouse, but I realized that the button from wheel is not available. I used a lot this button to close tabs or to open links in new tabs.

How can I replace this somehow? I also check in logitech options but didnt find anything good

Comment: Ctrl-W is an almost universal shortcut to close the currently open tab, applicable to many browsers, PDF viewers, tabbed text editors, etc.

Comment: I know that but that is not my question. If I have 6 tabs opened I have to enter individually each one and ctrl w

Comment: If you go to the last tab and **hold** the Ctrl-W key, it closes them one at a time, until none are left. Just let go the key to keep the remainder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that if I put the central button in mouse logitech option it will work like the wheel button :)

EDIT: Put central button configured in the buttonn bellow the wheel in logitech option

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on Windows, the free key-remapping product
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
can remap keys and mouse clicks.

For example, the following AutoHotkey script will remap:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left-click</kbd> to middle-click:

```
Ctrl & LButton:: MouseClick, Middle
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Answer (score 1):

[X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) allows you to remap your mouse buttons to do all kinds of stuff.

You can even map the buttons differently depending on the app. It's free.

Disclaimer: I am a happy user and have no affiliation with the product or it's owner.

Comment: I'm also happy btw